# Zippo lighter barely giving any spark

Tags: fire

So I got a zippo as birthday gift, which I used only for about 6 months or so.
Meanwhile I always used ONLY original flints and fuel, never anything else. Last couple of weeks it got harder and harder to light it, as problem was the spark. (I was able to light it with other source of fire very easily, so the gas fluid was present with no problem. Even the fire was solidly big).

The thing is, it works "okay" with new Zippo flint, but only 5-10 sparks, then it won't light again.
Is it possible that the flint wheel got worn out only after couple of months (5-6 to be precise)?
I can't put in new flint for every 5 lights and then just change it again.

Comment: You've used it for 6 months, but how much do you use it? A heavy smoker could use it dozens of times per day, but someone lighting the odd campfire much less.  I wonder about contamination on the wheel

Comment: Hey, that's a good question, which I probably forgot to mention. I use it quite some. I had to refuel it 1-2 per week. I used it not only for smoking, but for burning the nylon thread, when I was working behind my leather sewing bench.
And if the wheel is contaminated (which was also one of my guessing), what am I supposed to do to make it work again?
(other assumption was that the wheel lost it's sharpness and went dull)

Comment: It's years since I've had one, but it looks like the wheels can be cleaned and even replaced.  I'd try a stiff brush first, unless you have an idea of something specific that could have got on it

Comment: Tried with dremmel and brass brush, doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Zippo has a lifetime warranty program.  The wheel should last longer than 6mo.  Send it back.

Comment: This is not really on topic for our site. The stackexchange format is supposed to be for questions and answers that have some long-lasting value, not questions about a particular product.

Comment: meta: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/questions-about-specific-products-replacement-parts-products-only-tangentially

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no outdoor content

Comment: restretch the spring that pushes the flint up.

Answer (score 1):

If the spark wheel isn't working, Zippo has a lifetime warranty per https://www.zippo.com/pages/repairs-windproof-lighter -- try sending it in for repair.

[image]